# Issues with JButtons and ActionListeners

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener, imageicon

So I have a paint program with multiple JButtons, the only way i know how to relate that button with the action of that button being click is to do something like if (e.ActionCommand().equals("Label of the button here"); and if the label matches I know I have the correct action. But here is my problem. I am trying to change my JButtons to be images, so instead of having JButton first = new JButton("Hello"); I am trying to have JButton first = new JButton(new ImageIcon("c:/.....")) and then have the image, This works. However my problem is, is that after this I don't know how to reference the button to make it actually do something. Thanks!!!

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
     import javax.swing.*;
     import javax.swing.border.Border;
     import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

     import java.awt.*;
     import java.awt.event.*;
     import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.util.*;


     public class PaintProgram extends JPanel implements MouseListener,ActionListener
     {
public static int stroke, eraser = 0;
private int xX1, yY1 , xX2, yY2, choice ;

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    new PaintProgram();
}

PaintProgram()
{


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Paint Program");
    frame.setSize(1200, 800);
    frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(this);


    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
    menuBar.add(help);
    JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
    help.add(about);
    about.addActionListener(this);



    JButton button1 = new JButton("Clear");
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    JButton color = new JButton("Color");
    color.addActionListener(this);
    JButton erase = new JButton("Erase?");
    erase.addActionListener(this);
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Empty Rect");
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    JButton button3 = new JButton("Filled oval");
    button3.addActionListener(this);
    JButton button4 = new JButton("Filled Rect");
    button4.addActionListener(this);
    JButton button5 = new JButton("Empty oval");
    button5.addActionListener(this);
    JButton button6 = new JButton("Line");
    button6.addActionListener(this);
    JRadioButton thin = new JRadioButton("Thin Line");
    thin.addActionListener(this);
    JRadioButton medium = new JRadioButton("Medium Line");
    medium.addActionListener(this);
    JRadioButton thick = new JRadioButton("Thick Line");
    thick.addActionListener(this);


    ButtonGroup lineOption = new ButtonGroup( );
    lineOption.add(thin);
    lineOption.add(medium);
    lineOption.add(thick);

   this.add(button1); 
   this.add(color);
   this.add(erase);
   this.add(button2);
   this.add(button3);
   this.add(button4);
   this.add(button5);
   this.add(button6);
   this.add(thin);
   this.add(medium);
   this.add(thick);
   addMouseListener(this);
   frame.setVisible(true);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{ 
     super.paintComponent(g);  
     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
     if(grid == null){
        int w = this.getWidth();
        int h = this.getHeight();
        grid = (BufferedImage)(this.createImage(w,h));
        gc = grid.createGraphics();
        gc.setColor(Color.BLUE);
     }

     g2.drawImage(grid, null, 0, 0);
     check();
}
BufferedImage grid;
Graphics2D gc;


public void draw()
{
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)getGraphics();
     int w = xX2 - xX1;
        if (w<0)
        w = w *(-1);

   int h = yY2-yY1;
        if (h<0)
        h=  h*(-1);

     switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            check();
            gc.drawRect(xX1, yY1, w, h);
            repaint();
            break;

        case 2:
            check();
            gc.drawOval(xX1, yY1, w, h);
            repaint();
            break;

        case 3:
            check();
            gc.drawRect(xX1, yY1, w, h);
            gc.fillRect(xX1, yY1, w, h);
            repaint();
            break;

        case 4:
            check();
            gc.drawOval(xX1, yY1, w, h);
            gc.fillOval(xX1, yY1, w, h);
            repaint();
            break;  

        case 5:

            if (stroke == 0)
            gc.setStroke(new BasicStroke (1));
            if (stroke == 1)
            gc.setStroke(new BasicStroke (3));
            if (stroke == 2)
            gc.setStroke(new BasicStroke (6));
            gc.drawLine(xX1, yY1, xX2, yY2);
            repaint();
            break;

        case 6:
            repaint();
            Color temp = gc.getColor();
            gc.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            gc.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            gc.setColor(temp);
            repaint();
            break;   

        case 7:

            if (eraser == 1)
            {
                gc.clearRect(xX1, yY1, w, h);
            }
            else
            {

            }
            break;
    }
}

public void check()
{
    if (xX1 > xX2)
    {
        int z = 0;
        z = xX1;
        xX1 = xX2;
        xX2 =z;
    }
    if (yY1 > yY2)
    {
        int z = 0;
        z = yY1;
        yY1 = yY2;
        yY2 = z;
    }
}




public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Color"))
{
     Color bgColor
     = JColorChooser.showDialog(this,"Choose Background Color", getBackground());
   if (bgColor != null)
     gc.setColor(bgColor);
}


if (e.getActionCommand().equals("About"))
{
    System.out.println("About Has Been Pressed");
    JFrame about = new JFrame("About");
    about.setSize(300, 300);
    JButton picture = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/TehRobot/Desktop/Logo.png"));
    about.add(picture);
    about.setVisible(true);
}

if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Empty Rect")) 
{         
  System.out.println("Empty Rectangle Has Been Selected~");
   choice = 1;

  }

if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Empty oval")) 
{         
 System.out.println("Empty Oval Has Been Selected!");
   choice = 2;
  }


if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Filled Rect"))
{         
  System.out.println("Filled Rectangle Has Been Selected");
   choice = 3;
  }


if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Filled oval")) 
{         
 System.out.println("Filled Oval Has Been Selected");
   choice = 4;
  }


if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Line"))
{
    System.out.println("Draw Line Has Been Selected");
    choice = 5;
}

if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Thin Line"))
{
    stroke = 0;
}

if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Medium Line"))
{
    stroke = 1;
}

if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Thick Line"))
{
    stroke = 2;
}

if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Erase?"))
{
    eraser = 1;
    choice = 7;
}

if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Clear"))
{         
    System.out.println("Clear All The Things!!!");
    choice = 6;
    draw();
}


 }

 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt){}
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt){}
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){}
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)
 {

     xX1 = evt.getX();
     yY1= evt.getY();



   }
 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt)
 {
     xX2 =evt.getX();
     yY2=evt.getY();
     draw();
     eraser = 0;
   }
```

Comment: nobody wants to wade through tons of code - strip it down to the concrete problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use ActionListener and register the event to your button something like:

```
  yourButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {// your logic here;
    }});
```

As well here is a good link to understand how event listeners work http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html The way you are trying to handle the events makes your code hard to read and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You have several possibilities:

- keep the listener code as is, and call `setActionCommand` on each button
- use `e.getSource()` and test if the source is button1, or button2, etc.
- use one separate listener for each button, as shown by Bartzilla

This last method is usually the best one, because each button should be doing something different from the other ones. Having one giant method for all the buttons, with lots of `if` statements, is not very clean.

Also, naming your buttons `fillOvalButton`, `drawLineButton`, etc. would make the code much clearer than with button1, button2, etc.

Comment: naming conv., most complete answer +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an ImageIcon on the JButton and a way to identify it:

```
JButton b = new JButton(ImageIcon i, String name);
```

then use

```
JButton c = (JButton) e.getSource();
if (c.getText()).equals(name);
```

thats pseudocode but hope it helps